# Sql Server Trigger Fires Square Number of Times

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers

I am attempting to add a trigger to a table that logs the value of certain rows changed. Everything works as expected, except the trigger executes the number of rows squared times. For example, if I were to change the name of 5 items in the table in a bulk query, the trigger would log in the TriggerTable 25 entries. Each item is logged the number of of total items changed, so the first name change would be logged 5 times since there were 5 total name changes. Pasted a portion of the trigger below.

I have tried adding a `IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() <= 1` to no success. The rest of the functionality works great, except this part. Any advice is appreciated!

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger]
ON [dbo].[Table]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    IF UPDATE(Name)
        IF EXISTS(SELECT Name FROM inserted) AND EXISTS(SELECT Name FROM deleted)
            INSERT INTO TriggerTable (Id, ColumnName, OldValue, NewValue)
                SELECT i.Id, 'Name', d.Name, i.Name
                FROM deleted d, inserted i
                WHERE d.Name <> i.Name OR (d.Name IS NULL AND i.Name IS NOT NULL) OR (d.Name IS NOT NULL AND i.Name IS NULL)
        ELSE IF EXISTS(SELECT Name FROM inserted)
            INSERT INTO  TriggerTable (Id, ColumnName, NewValue)
                SELECT i.Id, 'Name', i.Name
                FROM inserted i
        ELSE IF EXISTS(SELECT Name FROM deleted)
            INSERT INTO  TriggerTable (Id, ColumnName, OldValue)
                SELECT d.Id, 'Name', d.Name
                FROM deleted d
```

Comment: *"except the trigger executes the number of rows squared times"* It doesn't "execute" that many times, it triggers once; a trigger only executes once per DML statement, not many. As for the problem that's because of your 1980's `CROSS JOIN` on `inserted` and `deleted`. I suggest using a 1992 `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: `IF UPDATE` does not do what you think it does. Many misunderstand the logic it implements - an understandable but common mistake. If your logic depends on an actual change to the value of a column, you **must** compare the old value against the new value to know that fact. For insert statements, everything is implicitly updated. Why your trigger is defined for delete makes no sense but that's a different issue.

Comment: Given the difference in logic, it's probably better to have separate `INSERT` and `UPDATE` triggers

Comment: @SMor What you say is true, however I think the use here is appropriate - they're using it to skip any updates that don't involve that column, and for the update case at least they are _trying_ to only log the rows where the value has changed (the logic just isn't quite right). What I don't want to think about is if there is a plan to create a block of code like this for every column in the table.

Comment: @TCR Have you considered change tracking, change data capture, temporal tables, or any built-in solutions that prevent you from doing all of this heavy (and error-prone) lifting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Larnu is correct that your join syntax is suboptimal, but it is hiding the underlying problem from you (and the problem is not that the trigger is executing many times).

Your current logic matches on *any row* where the name is different. If you update two rows, unless all four names are the same before and after, they're both going to match. You need to match on *any row* where the name is different *but only for the same `Id`*. As an example using #temp tables and each possible scenario (name changes, name doesn't change, name becomes NULL or becomes NOT NULL, or name stays NULL):

```
CREATE TABLE #deleted (Id int identity(1,1), name nvarchar(32));
CREATE TABLE #inserted(Id int identity(1,1), name nvarchar(32));

INSERT #deleted (name) VALUES('bob'),('frank'), (NULL),  ('bla'),(NULL);
INSERT #inserted(name) VALUES('bob'),('franky'),('boop'),(NULL), (NULL);

-- not correct:
SELECT i.Id, 'Name', d.Name, i.Name
  FROM #deleted d, #inserted i
  WHERE d.Name <> i.Name 
    OR (d.Name IS NULL AND i.Name IS NOT NULL) 
    OR (d.Name IS NOT NULL AND i.Name IS NULL)

-- correct:
SELECT i.Id, 'Name', d.Name, i.Name
  FROM #deleted AS d
  INNER JOIN #inserted AS i
  ON d.Id = i.Id
  WHERE d.Name <> i.Name 
    OR (d.Name IS NULL AND i.Name IS NOT NULL) 
    OR (d.Name IS NOT NULL AND i.Name IS NULL);
```

You need your join in the trigger to look more like the latter.

Also I will suggest always using `BEGIN`/`END` around logical blocks.

```
IF something
BEGIN
    do a bunch of stuff
END
```

...might be a bit more typing, but it is more predictable and intuitive for the reader than...

```
IF something
    do a bunch of stuff
```

Comment: Using the Inner Join worked! For anyone else in this situation, I also ended up separating the Insert, Update, and Delete into their own triggers. Made the code much more readable and concise; far fewer if statement checks and weird work arounds. I would recommend that approach to others in this situation.